# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression when calling function

Tags: javascript, html, jshint

I am making a flashcard/test program. For some reason, I'm not checking the result when I call the function getAns. JSHint is giving this error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Here's my code:

```js
function getAns() {
  if (answer[i] == lastPress) {
    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "You're correct! The answer was " + lastPress;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "We're sorry, but that is not correct. The answer was " + answer[i];
  }
  i++;
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[i];
}
document.getElementById("true").onclick = function() {
  lastPress = true
};
document.getElementById("true").onclick = function() {
  getAns
};
document.getElementById("false").onclick = function() {
  lastPress = false
};
document.getElementById("false").onclick = function() {
  getAns
};
```

Comment: `getAns` is an expression, not an assignment (`getAns = ...`) or function call (`getAns()`). Also you seem to be adding two different `onclick` functions to each element.

Comment: Re @jonrsharpe's second point: If you want to do two things in your handler, write one after another in a single handler function: `.onclick = function() { lastPress = true; getAns(); };` But also look at using modern event handling (`addEventListener`), rather than assigning to `onclick`.

Comment: Also `document.getElementById("true").onclick = function() {
  lastPress = true;
  getAns();
};`

Comment: Could you paste the code with the line numbers? Also pasting the exact error (with line number) would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting the error from using `getAns` as a statement and not calling it as a function.

Ideally, your onclick functions would pass the last keypress to `getAns()`. For example:

```
document.getElementById("true").onclick = function() {
   getAns(true);
};
```

And your handler would receive the value:

```
function getAns(lastPress) {
    ...
}
```